# Rails "rake test" crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rake

this might be rather unspecific, but I'm trying to do 'rake test' on a new rails app, and end up with

```
(in /Users/myname/dev/railstest/RailsApplication1)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"
```

No other output, log is empty.

System is Leopard 10.5, Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.86

Any ideas  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I tried all the subtests and it turned out to be the profiler test, which crashed because of a non existing ruby-prof gem.

So

```
sudo gem install ruby-prof
```

solved it.